# gradle and C++ plugin using clang, include as system headers?

Tags: c++, gradle, clang

Gradle can be used to compile C++ code.

Of course, one can define dependencies on third party libraries, like boost, for example:

```
repositories {
  libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
    boost_thread {
      binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
        staticLibraryFile = file("third_party/boost/lib/libboost_system.a")
      }
      headers.srcDir "third_party/boost/include/"
    }
  }
```

From my understanding in terms of headers this is somewhat similar to inclusion by:

```
-Ithird_party/boost/include
```

However directories inclusion can also be achieved (at least in clang 3.4) by invoking:

```
-isystem third_party/boost/include
```

Benefit being silencing warnings in the headers files.

And so the question is how to do this in gradle the right way?

I figured I could omit the headers directories within libs(PrebuiltLibraries) section and manually add them to the compiler args, but this seems more of a workaround.